# What is the price of real-time data in Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Will I pay more than reads when it comes to cloud-firestroe onSnapshot() ?

```js
import { doc, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";

const unsub = onSnapshot(doc(db, "cities", "SF"), (doc) => {
    console.log("Current data: ", doc.data());
});
```

I am afraid that I will pay more by data transferred, so is it a read pay or other fees might apply ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you [listen for realtime updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) to a single document, you pay 1 document read when a client attaches that listener and it gets the document data from the server, and 1 more document read each time the document gets updated and your listener gets the updated document data from the server.

In both cases you also pay for the bandwidth used to transfer the data from the server to the listening client.

Also see the Firebase [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing).

Comment: bandwidth don't apply if I am only getting the document then using the classic get..

Comment: Why would bandwidth usage not apply in that case? The same billing logic applies when using `get()` as when using `onSnapshot`, but you will at most pay for bandwidth once - since you're at most transferring the document data once.

Comment: my current Realtime data is on a doc that could reach 0.75 of mb and if will have to fetch this many times using Realtime listener i could be shooting my self in the foot. yet big thanks for the answer.

Comment: Don't just look at the number of fetches though, also look at the update frequency. If the document updates frequently and you `get()` every update, that's not gonna be any cheaper than keeping an `onSnapshot` on the document.

Comment: I am manipulating local state to avoid extra gets, since the update frequency is kind of frequent,  other wise I will go for snapShot, in my chat component I have to go snapShot regardless but the point here to use the snapShot where it is very logical to do so, you know about those horror stories where a bad implementation rendered a bill with 3k usd.